# Is there a way I can use a method from api 19 in earlier versions?

Tags: android, json, api

I've built an application that depends on the remove() method of the JSONArray class to in some cases remove the first entry.
Even if hacky, this works fine, however it has now been deemed necessary for the application to also work on earlier android versions and this method was apparently introduced in api 19.

Is there a way to use this method in earlier versions? Otherwise, could you suggest an alternate way of removing the first object from the array?

Comment: see if the method is available in the support-library. If yes use it from the support library else try another approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's available in support library then go ahead and use it. Otherwise , you will have to find other ways (use third-party library or copy the source code and implement your own).

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this? How can I determine whether it is or not available in the support library?

Comment: Just google for xxx feature in android support library, and you can find useful information from http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html